# Change dynamically image according to the selected combobox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working one task i.e change image according to select the combobox item name. My task look like:

[image]

In this picture I have made one combobox in that having item name like photo1, photo2 and photo3.

So my question is that, after select the combobox selected item according to the selected item image will be change automatically and replace the heart image. So for this task I have used the html page and one external JavaSCript.

In html page whole UI is described while in external JavaScript other functionality are described.

Above show the html page code i.e.

```js
function addAnchor(group) {      
             group.add(anchor);
    }

    function loadImages(sources, callback) {
             var images = {};
             var loadedImages = 0;
             var numImages = 0;
             for(var src in sources) {
                 numImages++;
             }
             for(var src in sources) {
                 images[src] = new Image();
                 images[src].onload = function() {
                       if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                            callback(images);
                       }
                 };
                 images[src].src = sources[src];
              }
        }

        function initStage(images) {
                 var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                        container: "container",
                        width: 691,
                        height: 440
                    });
    
    var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        draggable: false
                    });
                    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    
    function addProduct( imgObj ){
           var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function() {
              var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 53,
                y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
                image: imageObj,
                width: 106,
                height: 118,
       draggable: true
              });
                // add the shape to the layer
              layer.add(image);
    
              // add the layer to the stage
         stage.add(layer);
      
         image.on("mouseover", function(){
        var imagelayer = this.getLayer();
        document.body.style.cursor = "move"; 
        this.setStrokeWidth(1);
        this.setStroke("#000000");
     layer.draw();   
      writeMessage(messageLayer, "Drag Image Into Position Double Click To Remove");    
    });
    
    var messageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      stage.add(messageLayer);
    
    // yoda
       var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
           x: 0,
           y: 0,
           image: images.yoda,
           width: 691,
           height: 450,
           name: "image"
       });
          yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);         
               stage.draw();
         }
                
        window.onload = function() {
               var sources = {

        //From here the static images has coming. I want to do dynamic // image as   per the combobox is selected item name is changed.

                   yoda: "images/heart.jpg" 
               };
               loadImages(sources, initStage); 
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/version1.js"></script>
          
        </head>
        <body>
           
            <div id="container" style="float:left; margin-right:40px;margin-top:10px;">       </div>
            <select name="Choice">
               <option value="Pic1.jpg">Photo 1</option>
               <option value="Pic2.jpg">Photo 2</option>
               <option value="Pic3.jpg">Photo 3</option>
            </select>
        </body>
        </html>
```

So here is my code and just I want to do the call the dynamic image as per the combobox selected item name is changed in windows load which I have comment from where the image is calling by JavaScript

Comment: Where is the default heart image in your posted code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the  image path according to the selected option of the select box,

**HTML :**

```
<select name="kitchen_color" id="kitchen_color" onchange="setImage(this);">
  <option value="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo4w.png">Google</option>
  <option value="http://yandex.st/www/1.645/yaru/i/logo.png">Yandex</option>
  <option value="http://limg.imgsmail.ru/s/images/logo/logo.v2.png">Mail</option>
</select><br />
<img src="" name="image-swap" />
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function setImage(select){
  var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
  image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Comment: Great. But TharinduLucky when I am doing same code. it shows the path in the alert but does not shows the image in the image div.                                 function setImage(select){
  var image = document.getElementById("container");
  
  image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  alert(image.src);
}

Comment: Thanks TharinduLucky. It is working. But after that it is coming one more error and that is the image is coming but it is not replace the same image infact it is creating new div and displaying in that.

Comment: To make your life easier, I put it in this snippet.. http://js.do/code/selectbox-image I don't see it's creating any divs